# Pass variable data between methods in same controller laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel-5.6

Hey guys how do u pass a variable between a `function` within the same controller? I have tried making a global variable and using `Session::` to set and get the values but neither of the method works. I am getting the values of the `start_date` and `end_date` from my generate.blade.php and pass the value to my `downloadPDF` function to filter the data based on the date range. Anyone able to enlighten me how can i accomplish this?

**GenerateReportController**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;

use App\Attendance;
use App\Subject;
use PDF;
use Session;  
use View;



class GenerateReportController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */

    public $start_date;
    public $end_date;

    public function index()
    {
        $this->start_date = Input::get('startDate');
        $this->end_date = Input::get('endDate');

        $subjects = Subject::all();
        return View::make('generate', compact('subjects',$subjects));
    }

    public function downloadPDF()
    {

        $dateBetween = Attendance::whereBetween('date',array($this->start_date, $this->end_date))->get();

        //dd($dateBetween);
        $pdf = PDF::loadView('pdf',compact('dateBetween'));
        $name = "Attendance Report";
        return $pdf->stream($name.'.pdf');
    }
}
```

**generate.blade.php**

```
@extends('master')

@section('page_header')
<div class="container-fluid">
    <h1 class="page-title">Attendance Records</h1>
    <a href="/dashboard/attendance/report/" target="_blank" class="btn btn-primary">
    <i class="voyager-list" style="font-size:15px;"></i>
    <span>Generate Report</span>
    </a>
</div>
@endsection

@section('content')
<div class="page-content browse container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="panel panel-bordered">
                <div class="panel-body">
                {!! Form::Label('subject', 'Subject:') !!}
                <select class="form-control" name="s_name">
                    @foreach($subjects as $subject)
                    <option value="{{$subject->s_name}}">{{$subject->s_name}}</option>
                    @endforeach
                </select>
                <br>
                {!! Form::Label('startDate', 'Start Date:') !!}<br>
                {!! Form::input('date', 'startDate', null,['id' => 'datetimepicker','class' => 'datepicker', 'data-date-format' => 'yy/mm/dd']) !!}
                <br>
                <br>
                {!! Form::Label('endDate', 'End Date:') !!}<br>
                {!! Form::input('date', 'endDate', null, ['id' => 'datetimepicker','class' => 'datepicker', 'data-date-format' => 'yy/mm/dd']) !!}

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

**web.php**

`Route::get('dashboard/attendance/generate','GenerateReportController@index');`
`Route::get('dashboard/attendance/report','GenerateReportController@downloadPDF');`

Comment: Create a post/get route for `downloadPDF()` and submit the form in that route. pass $request parameter in `downloadPDF($request)`. And access it `$request->start_date`

Comment: @EmptyBrain i have updated my route do let me know if im doing it correctly

Comment: its better to pass date as params : dashboard/attendance/report?start=start_date&end=end_date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SOLVED**

Instead of passing the variable one a function to another. Use a post method to send the `$request` to the second controller and use `$request->name` to get the value.

**Controller**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;

use App\Attendance;
use App\Subject;

use Session;
use PDF;
use View;

class GenerateReportController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $subjects = Subject::all();
        return View::make('generate', compact('subjects'));
    }

    public function downloadPDF(Request $request)
    {

        $dateBetween = Attendance::whereBetween('date',array($request->startDate,$request->endDate))->where('s_code',$request->id)->get();
        $pdf = PDF::loadView('pdf',compact('dateBetween'));
        $name = "Attendance Report";
        return $pdf->stream($name.'.pdf');
    }
```

**Blade View**

```
{!! Form::open(['action'=>'GenerateReportController@downloadPDF','target' => '_blank']) !!}
{!! Form::Label('subject', 'Subject:') !!}
<select class="form-control" name="id">
    @foreach($subjects as $subject)
    <option value="{{$subject->id}}">{{$subject->s_name}}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
<br>
{!! Form::Label('startDate', 'Start Date:') !!}<br>
{!! Form::date('startDate', 'startDate',['id' => 'datetimepicker','class' => 'datepicker']) !!}
<br>
<br>
{!! Form::Label('endDate', 'End Date:') !!}<br>
{!! Form::date('endDate', 'endDate',['id' => 'datetimepicker','class' => 'datepicker']) !!}
<br>
<br>
{!!Form::submit('Generate PDF',['class' => 'btn btn-primary'])!!}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

**web.php**

```
Route::get('dashboard/attendance/generate','GenerateReportController@index');
Route::post('dashboard/attendance/report','GenerateReportController@downloadPDF');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like below

In Route

```
 Route::get('dashboard/attendance/report','GenerateReportController@downloadPDF');
```

First add this facade in your controller

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
```

After convert your function to

```
public function downloadPDF($request)
{
    //try to print first dd($request->all())
    $dateBetween = Attendance::whereBetween('date',array($request->start_date, $request->end_date))->get();

    //dd($dateBetween);
    $pdf = PDF::loadView('pdf',compact('dateBetween'));
    $name = "Attendance Report";
    return $pdf->stream($name.'.pdf');
}
```

Form

```
{!! Form::open(['action'=>'GenerateReportController@downloadPDF']) !!}
{!! Form::Label('subject', 'Subject:') !!}
<select class="form-control" name="s_name">
    @foreach($subjects as $subject)
    <option value="{{$subject->s_name}}">{{$subject->s_name}}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
<br>
{!! Form::Label('startDate', 'Start Date:') !!}<br>
{!! Form::input('date', 'startDate', null,['id' => 'datetimepicker','class' => 'datepicker', 'data-date-format' => 'yy/mm/dd']) !!}
<br>
<br>
{!! Form::Label('endDate', 'End Date:') !!}<br>
{!! Form::input('date', 'endDate', null, ['id' => 'datetimepicker','class' => 'datepicker', 'data-date-format' => 'yy/mm/dd']) !!}
{!! Form::submit('Submit') !!}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Comment: i have tried the solution you gave and unfortunately it did not return any data in my PDF view. I tried `dd($request->start_date)` and it is returning null

Comment: @DexterSiah please please try `dd($request->all())` First to see your request parameters. i think  you values are in `date` key. DID you check it??

Comment: it is returning `[]` am i missing anything or did u misinterpreted how i want to get my `date`. The 'start_date' and 'end_date' is is captured from the `index' controller( generate view) and i want to pass it to 'generatePDF' controller (pdf view)

Comment: The form should work. did you check the updates?? Other way like you saying index function already captured the value you can send it like  `$this->downloadPDF($start_date, $end_date)`

Comment: May i know where should i put that line of code in?